# Unit testing of exported function using react / enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have an exported function, which I import and use in my react component:

```
//in App.js
import { getSum } from "../helpers/helpers.js;
//some react component code here.

//in helpers.js
export function getSum(arg1, arg2){return arg1+arg2; }
```

in my test suite, normal testing of non-imported react components is fine, but 
but I am not sure how to call the exported "helper" function in the other file.

```
describe('App', () => {

it('correctly calculates the sum of 1 and 3', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
        assert.equal(wrapper.instance().getSum(1, 3), 4);
    });

});
```

results in

```
 TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).getSum is not a function
        at Context.<anonymous> (client/test/index.js:191:5325)
```

How would I properly locate and call the function "getSum" in my test suite?

Comment: seeing `Context` in the error suggests that you are importing a wrapped `App` component, maybe a `react-redux` `connect()`?

Comment: Are you just trying to test the `getSum` export from `helpers.js`?  If that is the case then create a test file (ex, `helpers.test.js`) and import/test `getSum` directly.  If `App` uses `getSum` then you will need to share the code for `App` for a specific answer.  One issue I see right now is that `instance()` only exists for Enzyme's full DOM rendering using `mount`, an instance is never created when using `shallow`.

Comment: Please post code for you App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just importing the function from the helper file and calling it

```
import { getSum } from "../helpers/helpers.js;"

describe('App', () => {

it('correctly calculates the sum of 1 and 3', () => {
        assert.equal(getSum(1, 3), 4);
    });

});
```

This works, however, it doesn't seem that optimized as the I feel that an instance of the react component should already contain this; but this is a working solution.